# SSH get trace to host

Tags: ssh, debian, xen

When using some kind of XEN VM's as user, how can I get trace to host where SSH leads to?

I encountered problem, that when listening SSH server on ip from ifconfig, I couldn't connect to it. Need to get know on what IP should I listen to incoming connections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like [tcptraceroute](http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/) from the client machine? That will reveal the network path without falling foul of firewalls that are blocking icmp.

Or are you saying you don't know which interface you need to have SSH listening on? If that's what you mean then you can infer the answer from your routing table, so for example if your client machine is `192.168.1.1` and your server is multi homed with interfaces `eth0 172.16.1.2` and `eth1 10.0.0.2`

```
$ ip route get 192.168.1.2
192.168.1.2 via 172.16.1.1 dev eth0 src 172.16.1.2 
cache
```

Would tell you that ssh needs to listen on eth0

Comment: great, that helped :)